# Pentaho PDI - Not setting constant

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I can't for the life of me figure out why my transform which I have setting a 'constant' value is not setting it? Anywhere I can look for details?

[image: flow]

Here's the add header - constant step

[image]

So WHY do I not get my test value in the output??

[image]

I even tried 'set field value to constant' step which takes the one row coming from my filer step and sets it to a constant value which also produces nothing! IDK whats going on here!

[image]

Comment: Is the step actually getting any input rows? You have several steps (Sample rows and filter rows) that might not be sending any rows through. Check out "Step metrics" to see where the input rows go. Also, in your first image the filter rows output to the add constants step is not marked correctly.

Comment: simple way to debug is right click on each and every step and click on preview data, you will be able to figure out the issue and come to know from which step it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions… I actually figured this out it has to do with the fact that the text output steps have a setting to not create when the transformation first starts I had to check that box…